# Oracle Client 11g R2 x86 on Solaris

Tags: solaris

When i want to execute the ./runInstaller file the following message occurs:

> .oui: Cannot find /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
>
> Killed

FYI:

OS: Solaris 11_2-text-x86

Oracle Client: Oracle Client 11g R2 x86-64

Which configuration i need to adjust?

And yes, Java jdk (1.7) is allready installed default.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you are installing the wrong package.  Solaris by default does not have a /lib64 directory,  Linux may.  This question is better suited for superuser.com, it is not programming related.

Answer (score 1):

`/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` indicates you downloaded the Linux version by mistake.  You need to download the Solaris version for Solaris, not the Linux version - they're not binary compatible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can only see the Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Client (SPARC) but my Solaris OS isn´t sparc. When i still install the sparc version (64 bit) i get this message: ./runInstaller: line 222: install/.oui: cannot execute [Invalid argument]

Comment: @aykon: To run on Solaris x86 you need the Solaris x86 version, not Solaris SPARC, nor Linux x86.   I have no problem seeing it on the Oracle Instant Client download page at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html or on the Oracle 11g R2 download page at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index-092322.html so perhaps you need to check again?